# Agular In deployment

Tags: angular

I have an angular app. It`s working without any errors. But after deployment when reload the full

page return 404 error

I expect my app work when full reload the page after deployment.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISuQG.png)

please any suggested solutions.

Comment: Add more details regarding your server setup/deployment process.
The 404 error and the image add very little to allow for actual understanding of where the problem could be.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly caused by your server setup. The server is saying that /Home is not found. The server is certainly trying to reach a file or folder named Home in the angular build.

Since the /Home is added by the Angular Router, it should not be considered by the server, server should be instructed to always serve the angular's index.html file.

One easy way to fix this is to make it fallback to the index.html if the requested file does not exist. Unfortunately, the exact details how depend on server setup and is out of scope of the current OP.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your ".htaccess" file. if you do not have file then create one,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

---

When you encounter a "404 Not Found" error when reloading the page in an Angular app, it typically means that the server hosting your application is not properly configured to handle Angular's routing.

To fix this issue, you need to configure your server to redirect all requests to the index.html file, which is the entry point of your Angular application. This allows Angular's routing to take over and handle the request appropriately.

The specific configuration steps depend on the server you are using for hosting. Here are the configuration steps for some commonly used servers.

Comment: can you show me more details

Answer (score -1):

The 404 error you are encountering after deploying your Angular app and then trying to reload the page typically indicates an issue with server-side routing configuration or how your server handles requests for routes in your Angular application.

Angular supports two types of routing strategies: PathLocationStrategy and HashLocationStrategy. The PathLocationStrategy uses clean URLs (e.g., /products/123), which can cause 404 errors when you reload the page because the server doesn't recognize those routes. To avoid this, you can switch to HashLocationStrategy, which uses URLs with a hash fragment (e.g., /#/products/123) that doesn't affect server-side routing.

To enable hash routing, you can configure it in your app.module.ts:

```
import { RouterModule, Routes, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [ Define your routes here];

@NgModule({imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { use Hash: true })],exports: [RouterModule],providers: [{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }]})
```

Also check for Base href in index.html

In your index.html file, make sure you have set the  element correctly. It should match the base URL of your deployed app.